# ASP.Net Identity to custom table reference using a third table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity

I would like to know how should I use Identity from ASP.NET In order to create Tables for linking 2 different tables.

For example we have ASP.NetUsers and ASP.NetRoles. Default identity provider will generate a ASP.NetUsersRoles for storing roles assigned to an user.

I would like to do the same for 2 other tables. Let's say I have default users table and a table called Context.

I would like to have ASP.NetUsers, Contexts and ASP.NetUsersContexts for linking a user one or more contexts.

What I have now is Context table with a foreign key inside Asp.Net Users table which I would like to get rid of and use Relationship tables. Is It Possible?

This is how I have it now:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public virtual ApplicationUserProfile UserProfile {get;set;}
        public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserContext> UserContext { get; set; }

        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: having a third table if for many to many relationships, but it sounds like you are asking about a one to many relationship, I.E. identityuser has a list of usercontexts, and usercontext only has one user. Is this the case? The example you gave with roles and users has a third table because a user can have many roles, and roles can have many users

Comment: @Steve no, it's a different context in my case. And i have the following scenarios
1) One user multiple contexts
2) Multiple users same context(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the code you have you need to add the following on your ApplicationUserContext class:

```
public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users {get;set;}
```

You also will need to make sure your dbcontext class has a property that returns a dbset of type ApplicationUserContext's:

```
public DbSet<ApplicationUserContext> Courses { get; set; }
```

it may already have this.

What this does is setup up a many to many relationship between the two classes and EF will generate a mapping table to keep track of this relationship.

Comment: Thanks. This was the solution